# Are there any STL headers which are not part of the C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I know that some C++ Standard Library headers are originated from the STL, such as `vector`. But I'm failing to find an up-do-date list of STL headers which are still not incorporated by the Standard Library. Do they exist?

PS: I would like to have them listed, and also to know if all major implementations include them or where to get them, if possible.

Comment: I'd say that by now, the C++ standard library is way larger than the STL.

Comment: [Sure; for instance, `rope` is missing](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)

Comment: @Agnew:  That may be true, but there are things that were part of the STL that were never adopted, such as `rope<>`

Comment: @Marc.2377:  Don't know if it can be considered authoritative or up to date, but you might check here:  https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

Comment: I think `rope` is the only major piece of functionality in the STL that was never incorporated into standard C++ in any form. We might not have `<hash_set>` but we do have `<unordered_set>` now which is almost the same.

Comment: In addition to headers that are completely missing, some of the standard library headers that do match STL header names don't contain exactly the same templates. For example, both the standard library and STL have headers named `functional`, but the STL version includes (among other things) `select1st` and `select2nd`, which the standard library version doesn't.

Comment: I am not sure, but can "boost" be considered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note, this is a function by function break down, rather than a by header breakdown, because it seems to be more useful.

If we examine [SGI's documentation of the STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) we find the following:

1. `slist` has been renamed `std::forward_list`.
2. `bit_vector` has been replaced by a template specification of `std::vector<bool>`.  The implementation of this may (not must) optimize for space in the way that `bit_vector` does.
3. `hash_set` and friends are now spelled like `unordered_set`.  Functionality seems to be the same. (Thanks T.C.!)
4. `rope` is missing.  There is no equivalent data structure in the standard library.  I could not find a relevant WG21 discussion on the topic.
5. `sequence_buffer` is missing, because this was primarily used for back inserting a `rope`.
6. `random_sample` and `random_sample_n` are missing.  The reason is discussed in N3547:

   > After WG21 consideration at the Sophia-Antipolis meeting, Austern updated the proposal.
   >   Among other changes, he withdrew [`random_sample` and `random_sample_n`]: “The LWG was concerned that they might not be well enough understood for standardization. . . . It may be appropriate to propose
   >   those algorithms for TR2” [
   >   Aus08b
   >   ]. The wiki minutes of the discussion are equally terse: “Bjarne
   >   feels rationale is insufficient. PJ worries we will get it wrong. Lawrence worries that people will
   >   roll their own and get it wrong. Good candidate for TR2” [
   >   LWG08
   >   ]. The subsequent vote regarding
   >   these proposed algorithms achieved a solid LWG consensus (10-1, 2 abs.) in favor of their future
   >   inclusion in a Technical Report (now termed a Technical Specification)

A version of the `random_sample_n` algorithm has made it to the Library Fundamentals TS and is called `std::experimental::sample`, the latest iteration of the proposal N3925 was adopted in 2014-02 but remains not yet part of the standard, I suppose we'll see in in C++17. (Thanks T.C.!)

7. `lexicographical_compare_3way` is missing.  It was seen as "not important enough" to standardize according to N2666.
8. `power` is spelled `pow` and does not have the generalized capabilities that `power` does.
9. `identity`, `project1st`, `project2nd`, `select1st` and `select2nd` never made it to standardization.  I could not find a discussion regarding why.
10. `subtractive_rng` is missing as well.  Presumptively because `<random>` would be superseding this problem space.
11. `binder1st`, `binder2nd`, `ptr_fun`, `pointer_to_unary_function`, `pointer_to_binary_function`, `mem_fun` (and friends), `unary_compose`, and `binary_compose` are missing or deprecated.  They are more or less superseded by `std::bind` and friends.
12. `construct` and `destroy` have been moved into the `allocator` class and do not exist as standalone functions. (Thanks T.C.!)
13. `temporary_buffer` is missing.  But `get_temporary_buffer` and `return_temporary_buffer` are available.  I haven't been able to find out exactly why, but what chatter I have ran across seems to imply that it's broken in some way pretty fundamentally, and lots of people have been trying to fix it.  Exactly what and how remains a mystery to me.

Comment: Please let me know if I have any specifics wrong, I will update them.  This is a rather complex answer, and I've more than likely made a few mistakes.

Comment: We have `unordered_meow` instead of `hash_meow`.

Comment: Also, [`std::experimental::sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/sample) is essentially `random_sample_n`, I think. `construct` and `destroy` are now member functions of the allocator, with a default supplied by `allocator_traits`.

Comment: `std::experimental` does not seem to be part of the standard?

Comment: No, it's in the library fundamentals TS.