# C++ Standard Library vs STL

Tags: c++

If the C++ Standard Library now contains many parts that were part of the STL(as created by Alexander Stepanov) is there still a use for the STL? In other words are there any parts of the STL that are useful and haven't been included in the C++ 'Core Language' or Standard Library?

Comment: STL is a subset of the standard library.

Comment: @IvanRubinson - There is a fair bit of the STL that isn't in the standard library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218197/are-there-any-stl-headers-which-are-not-part-of-the-c-standard-library

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "although the C++ Standard Library and the STL share many features, neither is a strict superset of the other."

Comment: How common is it that someone would actually use the STL. And would it be beneficial for someone trying to go into C++ programming to learn the STL?

Comment: @Lauren learn standard library instead. STL is part of history

Comment: Thanks @Swift that's what i was thinking but I wasn't completely sure.